# How to use OAuth with Office 365 Reporting web service

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

Using this page as reference, we are creating an application to get MessageTrace from Office 365 Reporting web service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/o365-enterprise-developers/jj984346(v=office.15)

However, this page has not been updated, and the authentication method is Basic authentication.
I want to authenticate with oAuth. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of.  We're using the same API to get message trace using basic auth.

Comment: Thank you.
Try to contact MS support. . .